# \MakeShortVerb{\§} and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Tags: verbatim, unicode

I have a book published more than 10 years ago. It contains the following code in its preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb{\§}

\begin{document}
§\begin{i}§
\end{document}
```

Now I want to convert source files to unicode. However after changing `cp1251` encoding to `utf8`

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

compilation stopped with error message indicating on a problem with `\MakeShortVerb{\§}`:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.8 \MakeShortVerb{\В§}

? h
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

? h
Sorry, I already gave what help I could...
Maybe you should try asking a human?
An error might have occurred before I noticed any problems.
``If all else fails, read the instructions.''

? 

! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 \MakeShortVerb{\В§}

? r
```

**How to bypass this problem?** Nothing to say that I still want to use `§` as delimiters for short verbatim text. **Is `shortverb` package compatible with `utf8` encoding?**

Comment: Did you actually change the file's encoding? Where is the `B` in `\B...` coming from?

Comment: @cfr: Yes, I have changed actual encoding in source files, but as you see the error occurs in the preamble of the main file.

Comment: If you posted a complete example, of course, somebody could actually test it or something.

Comment: However, if I had to guess, I'd say you are using a character which is really two for `utf8` and that you therefore get the error because there is a second character where the `\endcsname` should be. The character may be encoded as a single character in `cp1251` but for `utf8` to work with 8-bit engines, as I understand it, some apparently single characters are really a sequence of two characters.

Comment: @cfr: Done, MWE is here.

Comment: Don't know what I did but I've ended up with `\MakeShortVerb{\౔絰ᜓ⟠ˠ윰ᖘ嘀ᙑ}` ??!!

Comment: It is definitely the particular character and not the package generally, though.

Comment: How did you 'convert' the encoding of the file? Did you check that it actually converted properly? You might try running it through [`iconv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv).

Comment: As @cfr observes, in UTF-8 `§` is a two-byte char so this can't work: you can only make short verbatim chars which are a single octet in pdfTeX.

Answer (score 4):

@egreg again too quick. But I had lunch to prepare...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage{shortvrb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A7}{\IgorSVerb}
\def\IgorSVerb{\begingroup\def\IgorSVerb{\verb@egroup\endgroup}\verb^^a7}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Hello

§\begin{i}$&^\}{"'çÂ\]%§

§\begin{i}$&^\}{"'çÂ\]%§

\selectlanguage{english}

§\begin{i}$&^\}{"'çÂ\]%§

§\begin{i}$&^\}{"'çÂ\]%§<

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the main limitation is that `§` can now not be used in a standard verbatim or another `\verb`.

Comment: there is an extra  `<` at the end of the code sample which is a keyboard slip during copy paste.

Comment: This works with `pdflatex` but not with `xelatex`.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov with `xelatex` don't load `inputenc` and just use `\MakeShortVerb{\§}`,  it works !! and also you need `fontspec` not `fontenc`...

Comment: I use `ifxetex` package` and `\ifxetex ... \else ... \fi` constract for almost all my documents to provide portability between `pdflatex` and `xelatex` and sililartly for `lualatex`. In MWE I just omit this portion of my code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, in UTF-8, `§` is two byte long, but `\MakeShortVerb` wants only one.

The best I can offer is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begingroup\uccode`~="C2 \uppercase{\endgroup
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A7}{\verb~}}
\begingroup\uccode`~="A7 \uppercase{\endgroup\def~}{}

\begin{document}

§\begin{i}§

§{-{\§

\end{document}
```

The limitation is that no character that in UTF-8 is prefixed by `<C2>` can appear in the verbatim text: the list of forbidden characters is

```
¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿
```

that is, the Unicode range `00A1`–`00BF`.

[image]